# index of fetch array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

i want to get the index of td that the user clicked , i have an html table fill from database using php ...

this is my index.php :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Last 10 Results</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <thead>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <?php
        session_start();
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
        if (!$connect) {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        $results = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM family where parent_id = 0");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {    
        ?>
            <td onclick="window.location='index2.php'"
            <?php  $id = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['varname'] = $id;?>>
            <?php echo $row['name']?> <br/>
            <?php echo $row['description']?> <br/>
            <?php echo $row['parent_id']?> <br/>
            </td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my index2.php :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Last 10 Results</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <thead>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <?php
        session_start();
        $gg = $_SESSION['varname'];
        echo $gg;
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","test");
        if (!$connect) {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        $results = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM family where parent_id = '$gg' ");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        ?>
                <td>
                <?php echo $row['id']?> <br/>
                <?php echo $row['name']?> <br/>
                <?php echo $row['description']?> <br/>
                <?php echo $row['parent_id']?> <br/>
                </td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

now i want to take the "id" of the td that the user click on,, but this code always give me the last id in my database ...

what can i do ?

Comment: `index2.php?id=42`

Answer (score 1):

Replace in Index.php:

```
<td onclick="window.location='index2.php'"
```

With:

```
<td onclick="window.location='index2.php?parent_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'"
```

And in
Index2.php:

```
$gg = $_SESSION['varname'];
```

With:

```
$gg = (int)$_GET['parent_id'];
```

It's better to use $_GET variable for this than $_session (urls are search engine friendly)